# Storing a file into a database & uploading it in a webpage

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload, upload

### Background

I'm creating a website where the user can store an article as a file in the database and than upload the file's content into a page in the website using a form. The file may only contain text or image or both.

### Question

Can anyone walk me through this?

Comment: Have you tried something yet? You'd probably be better off storing the file location on your server in the DB rather than the file.

Comment: this isn't a *"show me how to..."* site, it's a *"let us help you with code you've already tried, but may have failed you"* type of site.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I'm not asking for a code I'm asking for a help like in what type I can store my file with in the DB. If I know a few stuff I can do the coding  myself .

Comment: the web is full of Q&A's that will most likely lead you back to Stack, where you can view many that have been asked and answered before. This is far too broad a question to be answered.

Comment: I already checked other question before asking .. If it did help I wouldn't ask !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a database table having fields having the userId, and path of the file.

The file uploaded should be saved in the Web Server, and its path need to be saved in the database.

The vice-versa should be done while retrieving the file content.

Comment: I already created a table for articles and I did put userId as foreign key. Is it possible to store it using BLOB ? If so how can I retrieve it. Thx alot.

Comment: I would suggest you not use blob in this case, as you may have files of different types. Rather than this, you can go ahead with storing the path, and use the WebServer's static content

Comment: OK !! I'll try this !! Thx alooooooooot !! :))

Comment: You are most welcome, hope that helped :)